# $X_n$ does not converge in probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution at $(0,1)$ and $X_n$ with uniform distribution at $(0, 1+1/n)$.

a) $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

b) Prove that $X_n$ does not converges in probability to $0$.

I was able to did the first exercise, but i'm stuck with b). I think I have to prove that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} P[|X_n|<\epsilon]$ does not converges to $1$. I would be thankful with any help.

Comment: $P[|X_n| \ge \epsilon] = P[ X_n \ge \epsilon] \to P[X \ge \epsilon] = \max(0,1-\epsilon)$..

Comment: Presumably the question wants you to use the convergence in distribution to conclude b)?

Comment: I don't think so. I think is to evidence the fact that $X_n$ could converges in distribution but not in probability.

Comment: Yes, but you can use the convergence in distribution to show that it does not converge in probability.

Comment: It does converge in probability, just not to $0$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I see, then with your argument I could conclude that converges in distribution but not in probability to $0$ since for any $0<\epsilon<1$ and the $\max(0,1-\epsilon)>0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the gist of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for any $\epsilon$ satisfying $0 < \epsilon < 1$,
$$P(|X_n| < \epsilon) = P(0 \leq X_n < \epsilon) = \int_{0}^{\epsilon}\dfrac{1}{1+1/n}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+1/n}\text{.}$$
Now take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Oh, so when $n \to  \infty$ , $P[|X_n|<\epsilon]=\epsilon$  but since $\epsilon < 1$ then $X_n$ does not converge in probability, right?

Comment: @Bayesianguy That's the essence of it. Make sure you understand *why* this suffices though: if $X_n$ were to converge in probability to $0$, then that would mean that **for each** $\epsilon > 0$, $P(|X_n| \leq \epsilon) \to 1$. Thus, to say that $X_n$ does **not** converge in probability to $0$ means that **there exists** an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $P(|X_n| \leq \epsilon) \to a \neq 1$.

Comment: I see, that is because the negation of the statement. I need to find some $\epsilon >0$ that satisfies the $\neq$. For that reason it is sufficient with the $0<\epsilon<1$ that you gave me. Thank you very much, I like when I understand in depth any exercise. Some day I would like to teach this exercise like you. Thanks!